# INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: no such file or directory

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When I was trying to use invokechaincode API to call the other chaincode data, the system return err, say it could not find that chaincode file.
Here is my command

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.trace.com:7050 -C mychannel -n sellcc --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/trace.com/orderers/orderer.trace.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.trace.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.sell.trace.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/sell.trace.com/peers/peer0.sell.trace.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["gethistory","s-001"]}'
```

and error message

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"InvokeChaincode error ......INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: transaction ID: 71993ee260225d1d4f9a5d7391294a730321e62aebc7d5c1e543e40f2f30b0d2: cannot retrieve package for chaincode dealercc/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/dealercc.1.0: no such file or directory"
```

sorry Im a very newbie in fabric, I try to search but it seems no such question.I think it may be caused by config or something, but i dont know how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Addition：
my code about chaincode invocation

```
text := t.getvalue(stub, args)
if text.Status != shim.OK {
    return shim.Error("getvalue error ......")
}
var result string
var fromID string

var sellItem SellInfo
json.Unmarshal(text.Payload, &sellItem)
fromID = sellItem.FromId
result += fmt.Sprintf("Sell:%s, ID:%s, FromID:%s <--- ", sellItem.Name, sellItem.Id, sellItem.FromId)

myArgs := [][]byte{[]byte("getvalue"), []byte(fromID)}
response := stub.InvokeChaincode("dealercc", myArgs, "mychannel") 
if response.Status != shim.OK {
    return shim.Error("InvokeChaincode error ......" + string(response.Payload))
}
var dealerItem DealerInfo
json.Unmarshal(response.Payload, &dealerItem)
fromID = dealerItem.FromId
result += fmt.Sprintf("Dealer:%s, ID:%s, FromID:%s <--- ", dealerItem.Name, dealerItem.Id, dealerItem.FromId)

myArgs = [][]byte{[]byte("getvalue"), []byte(fromID)}
response = stub.InvokeChaincode("hennrycc", myArgs, "mychannel") 
if response.Status != shim.OK {
    return shim.Error("InvokeChaincode error ......")
}
var hennryItem HennryInfo
json.Unmarshal(response.Payload, &hennryItem)
result += fmt.Sprintf("Hennry:%s, scale:%s, breed：%s 。 ", hennryItem.Name, hennryItem.Quality, hennryItem.Breed)

//jsonText, error := json.Marshal(myList)
//if error != nil {
//  return shim.Error("json.Marshal(myList) fail...")
//}
return shim.Success([]byte(result))
```

Comment: did you install and instantiate chaincode?

Comment: yes, and other operation like setvalue, getvalue worked well

Comment: please check if you are invoking the correct chaincode, i can see you are trying to invoke sellcc but getting dealercc in the logs

Comment: thats OK, because that is what invokechaincode API shall do, invoke data from other cc

Comment: have you implemented the chaincode to chaincode invocation?

Comment: @AdityaJoshi Yes, sure. I will post it

Comment: I am asking if you have implemented chaincode to chaincode calling in you chaincode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to solve it. All the chaincodes should be installed on the peer who use InvokeChaincode API by using 'peer chaincode install -n org1cc/org2cc'